# Node.js Express - How does res.render() create html with data when that data isn't passed to it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm using the *Getting MEAN With Mongo, Express, Angular, and Node* by Simon Holmes and in Chapter 7.2.3 *Using the API response data* section there is some very weird behavior.  It seems that html is being generated from res.render() with data not actually passed to it.  When the correct data is being passed, different errors occur depending on how the jade file is being manipulated. The following are **locations.js**, **index.js** and **locations-list.jade** files including terminal output showing an expected JSON.  All files are located within the **app_server** folder seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFLsB.jpg

For those not following along in the book this question only refers to `module.exports.homelist = function(req, res) {...}` being called, this taking place when there is a request from the browser at **localhost:3000/**. All other request such as **localhost:3000/location** behave as expected.  The key data mentioned in the previous paragraph is the response from the api request called **body** inside the **request** object. The res.render() function uses this data for **locations** and is called **responseBody**.

There are several options where code is commented out or uncommented in that produce different outputs as seen below. This takes place in the **locations.js** file in the **renderHompage** and **module.exports.homelist functions** except for Option Four.  The following are the options

1. Removing `locations: responseBody` from `var renderHomepage = function(req, res, responseBody) {...}` produces the following html seen in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLzi8.jpg
2. Including `locations: responseBody` for `var renderHomepage = function(req, res, responseBody) {...}` produces the following html seen in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQRCB.jpg
3. Using `var renderHomepage = function(req, res) {...}` produces the same output as the first option.
4. Removing lines 24 - 26 (everything involving facilities - see the error message from the second option) from **locations-list.jade** and using Option Two where `responseBody` is included produces https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fszu.jpg and that list of empty locations is more than a hundred so it can be scrolled down for quite a while.

Terminal output when ever localhost:3000 is requested from browser using Option One, Three and Four. Option two is similar except for `GET / 500 806.003 ms - 3396` in the proper place.

```
GET /api/locations?lng=-122.236353&lat=37.485217 200 19.818 ms - 297
[{"distance":285.97478710956176,"name":"Peet's Coffee","rating":0,"facilities":["hot drinks"," food"," classical music"],"_id":"5ae25bd42d69c6abe46ae307"},{"distance":700.0951415645783,"name":"Philz Coffee","rating":4,"facilities":["hot drinks"," food"," power"],"_id":"5ae25c472d69c6abe46ae30a"}]
GET / 304 128.077 ms - -
GET /bootstrap/css/amelia.bootstrap.css 304 3.148 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 4.557 ms - -
GET /javascripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js 304 8.150 ms - -
GET /bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 304 6.275 ms - -
GET /bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 304 0.551 ms - -
```

locations.js

```
var request = require('request');
var apiOptions = {
  server : "http://localhost:3000"
};
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
  apiOptions.server = "https://example.herokuapp.com/"; // not actual location
}

// var renderHomepage = function(req, res) { // uncomment for Option Three
//   res.render('locations-list', {
//     title: 'Loc8r - find a place to work with wifi',
//     pageHeader: {
//       title: 'Loc8r',
//       strapline: 'Find places to work with wifi near you!'
//     },
//     sidebar: "Looking for wifi and a seat? Loc8r helps you find places to work when out and about.  Perhaps with coffee, cake or a pint? Let Loc8r help you find the place you're looking for.",
//   });
// };

var renderHomepage = function(req, res, responseBody) { // comment out for Option Three
  res.render('locations-list', {
    title: 'Loc8r - find a place to work with wifi',
    pageHeader: {
      title: 'Loc8r',
      strapline: 'Find places to work with wifi near you!'
    },
    sidebar: "Looking for wifi and a seat? Loc8r helps you find places to work when out and about.  Perhaps with coffee, cake or a pint? Let Loc8r help you find the place you're looking for.",
    // locations: responseBody // comment out for Option One, uncomment out for Option Two
  });
};

/* GET 'home' page */
module.exports.homelist = function(req, res) {
  var requestOptions, path;
  path = '/api/locations';
  requestOptions = {
    url: apiOptions.server + path,
    method : "GET",
    JSON : {},
    qs : {
      lng : -122.236353,
      lat : 37.485217
    }
  };
  request(
    requestOptions,
    function(err, response, body){
      console.log(body);
      // renderHomepage(req, res);  // use for Option Three
      renderHomepage(req, res, body); // use for Option One and Two
    }
  );
};

/* GET 'Location info' page */
module.exports.locationInfo = function(req, res) {
    res.render('location-info', {
    title: 'Location info',
    name: 'Starcups',
    address: '125 High Street, Reading, RG6 1PS',
    rating: 5,
    facilities: ['Hot drinks', 'Premium wifi'],
    distance: '109m',
    description: " Simon's cafe is on Loc8r because it has accessible wifi and space to sit down with your laptop and get some work dont.",
    times: [
      "Monday - Friday : 7:00am - 7:00pm",
      "Saturday : 8:00am - 5:00pm",
      "Sunday : closed"
    ],
    reviews: [{
      name: "Simon Holmes",
      description: "What a great place. I can't say enough good things about it.",
      timestamp: "16 Febuary 2014",
      rating: 3
    },{
      name: "Judy Holmes",
      description: "It was okay. Coffee wasn't great, but the wifi was fast.",
      timestamp: "26 January 2015",
      rating: 3
    },{
      name: "Simon Cramp",
      description: "It was okay. Coffee wasn't great, but the wifi was fast.",
      timestamp: "6 September 2012",
      rating: 3
    },{
      name: "Simoolmes",
      description: "What a great place. I can't say enough good things about it.",
      timestamp: "14 June 2013",
      rating: 3
    }]
  });
};

/* GET 'Add review' page */
module.exports.addReview = function(req, res) {
    res.render('location-review-form', {
    title: 'Add review',
    name: 'Starcups' 
  });
};
```

locations-list.jade

```
extends layout

include _includes/sharedHTMLfunctions.jade

block content
  #banner.page-header
    .row
      .col-lg-6
        h1= pageHeader.title
          small &nbsp;#{pageHeader.strapline}
  .row
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-8
      .error= message
      .row.list-group
        each location in locations
          .col-xs-12.list-group-item
            h4
              a(href="/location/#{location._id}")= location.name
              small &nbsp;
                +outputRating(location.rating)
              span.badge.pull-right.badge-default= location.distance
            p.address= location.address
            p
              each facility in location.facilities
                span.label.label-warning= facility
                | &nbsp;              
    .col-xs.12.col-sm-4
      p.lead= sidebar
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ctrlLocations = require('../controllers/locations');
var ctrlOthers = require('../controllers/others');

/* Location pages */
router.get('/', ctrlLocations.homelist);
router.get('/location', ctrlLocations.locationInfo);
router.get('/location/review/new', ctrlLocations.addReview);

/* Other pages */
router.get('/about', ctrlOthers.about);

module.exports = router;
```

So the big question is how the html is displaying locations that aren't being passed into res.render() as can be seen in the first and third options?  Option One and Three are obviously very similar but I just had to double check because it just seems so weird.  I thought it was possible that the data was being cached somewhere so I changed the latitude longitude numbers in the requestOptions the html shows that change for Option One and Three

Not shown here I've replaced responseBody with hardcoded sample location data from earlier in the book similar to what is seen in `module.exports.locationInfo = function(req, res) {...}` and everything looked fine.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't tell what code is options 1, 2 and 3.  I see several calls to `res.render()` that are passing data with the call as the third argument.  What call to `res.render()` is including data in the rendered HTML, but you aren't passing any data to the render call?  Please break out that specific code on its own in the question to make it easier to see.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've tried to clarify by adding information in the new second paragraph. In Option One and Two `locations: responseBody` is commented out but shows up in rendered HTML.